# Create Doctrine Record Object Dynamically - Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I've had a quick search to find an answer for this but honestly im not even 100% on what to search for.

This is more of an optimisation issue than an actual problem but I could do with the help.

In my Symfony 1.4 project I have created some methods to "get or create objects" like so:

```
protected function getOrCreateManufacturer($name)
{
    $manufacturer = ManufacturerTable::getInstance()->findOneBy('name', $name);

    if(!$manufacturer)
    {
        $manufacturer = new Manufacturer();
        $manufacturer->setName($name);
    }

    return $manufacturer;
}
```

I have a few of these for different objects all of which do the exact same thing. I am trying to create a method that can replace a lot of the code inside these methods so that they can all call it like so:

```
protected function getOrCreateManufacturer($name)
{
    return $this->getOrCreateObject('Manufacturer', 'name', $name);
}

protected function getOrCreateObject($table, $field, $value)
{
    $object = Doctrine::getTable($table)->findOneBy($field, $value);

    if(!$object)
    {
        // create object here
        $object->set($field, $value);
    }

    return $object;

}
```

But I can't seem to find out how I can create an instance of my Objects.

The objects I'm trying to create all extend `sfDoctrineRecord`.

If I can't do it then thats fine but it'd be cool if its possible.

Cheers.

Comment: and 47 minutes later i figured it out.
You can call `new` just on the parameter `$table` and it creates the object. Magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a simple :

```
if(!$object)
{
    $object = new $table();
    $object->set($field, $value);
}
```

Comment: @dxd Haha, its fine. I'm glad you have the same solution though, makes me feel like i'm doing something right

Comment: @dxd I didn't use `new $table()` I just did `new $table` is there any difference between the two standard wise?

Comment: Thank you ! I don't think the () make any difference... You can read many different exemple ine the comments section of this page http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php